# Slicing a substring

Tags: vb.net

Trying to slice a sub-string out of a string. I have found methods of both searching for a sub-string, and slicing a string but only for the first instance of the slice bound. Below is what I am trying to do:

> string = "abcdabcdabcdabcd"

I want to cut out each of the b's using the bounds a and c to identify them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get it, but do you mean you want to eliminate all the 'b' in the string?

If so you could just replace it with `yourString.Replace('b','')`

Comment: No, my end goal is to read an html page and every time the code encounters <a href=" and "> write the link name to the console screen AND/OR store it in an array. The example I used was unclear to say the least. I can write a script to look for the html link tags <a href=" and "> but I do not understand how to loop over the whole block of html text and to read between each of the tag scripts I named. If you have any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated - thanks.

Comment: If you want to parse HTML, use a HTML parser.